# How do I handle no virtual method acquireEnvironmentalHdrCubeMap() error for ArSceneForm?

Tags: android, kotlin, augmented-reality

I've been struggling with this issue with AR SceneForm for Android Studio. I have Android Studio Giraffe version and testing with Samsung S20FE.  There's no error until after I've sent the application to the phone.  In the emulator, it used to work, but now it also pops up with this same error.  It scans the surroundings and then crashes with this error in the LogCat:

FATAL EXCEPTION: main
no                              Process: com.tritongames.shoppingwishlist, PID: 30842
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No virtual method acquireEnvironmentalHdrCubeMap()[Lcom/google/ar/core/ArImage; in class Lcom/google/ar/core/LightEstimate; or its super classes (declaration of 'com.google.ar.core.LightEstimate' appears in /data/app/~~1VrM8w5k4CFGFyaV560PNw==/com.tritongames.shoppingwishlist-xDIIOFiDf_g-A7qwedW2jg==/base.apk!classes14.dex)

```
                                                                                                    at com.google.ar.sceneform.ArSceneView.updateHdrLightEstimate(SourceFile:189)
                                                                                                    at com.google.ar.sceneform.ArSceneView.updateLightEstimate(SourceFile:135)
                                                                                                    at com.google.ar.sceneform.ArSceneView.onBeginFrame(SourceFile:124)
                                                                                                    at com.google.ar.sceneform.SceneView.doFrameNoRepost(SourceFile:90)
                                                                                                    at com.google.ar.sceneform.SceneView.doFrame(SourceFile:86)
                                                                                                    at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:1299)
                                                                                                    at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:1309)
                                                                                                    at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:923)
                                                                                                    at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:847)
                                                                                                    at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:1283)
                                                                                                    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:942)
                                                                                                    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
                                                                                                    at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:226)
                                                                                                    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:313)
                                                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8757)
                                                                                                    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                                                    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:571)
                                                                                                    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1067)
```

This is my build.gradle (app)

```
plugins {
id 'com.android.application'
id 'kotlin-android'
id 'kotlin-kapt'
id 'dagger.hilt.android.plugin'
id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android'

}

 android {
namespace 'com.tritongames.shoppingwishlist'
compileSdk 33

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.tritongames.shoppingwishlist"
    minSdk 24
    targetSdk 33
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"

    testInstrumentationRunner 'androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner'

    Properties properties = new Properties()
    properties.load(project.rootProject.file("local.properties").newDataInputStream())

    buildConfigField "String", "BEST_BUY_API_KEY", 
 "\"${properties.getProperty("BEST_BUY_API_KEY")}\""


}

buildFeatures {
    viewBinding true
}

buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 
   'proguard-rules.pro'
        debuggable true

    }
    debug {

    }
}
compileOptions {
    sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_17
    targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_17
}
kotlinOptions {
    jvmTarget = '17'
}
buildToolsVersion '34.0.0'
}

hilt {
enableAggregatingTask false
}
dependencies {

implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.10.1'
implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.6.1'
implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.9.0'
implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.4'

//Annotation
implementation 'javax.annotation:javax.annotation-api:1.3.2'
implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.11.0-beta02'
implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-ktx:2.6.1'

//Junit 4
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.2'
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.5'

//Espresso
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.5.1'

//Fragment
// Kotlin
implementation 'androidx.fragment:fragment-ktx:1.6.1'

//Dagger - Hilt
implementation "com.google.dagger:hilt-android:2.47"
kapt "com.google.dagger:hilt-android-compiler:2.47"
kapt "androidx.hilt:hilt-compiler:1.0.0"


// Activity KTX for viewModels()
implementation "androidx.activity:activity-ktx:1.7.2"

// Architectural Components
implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-ktx:2.6.1'

// Lifecycle
implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-extensions:2.2.0"
implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-livedata-ktx:2.6.1'
implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-runtime-ktx:2.6.1'


// Retrofit
implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.9.0'
implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.9.0'
implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:5.0.0-alpha.11'

// Coroutines
implementation 'org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-core:1.7.3'
implementation 'org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-android:1.7.3'

// Coroutine Lifecycle Scopes
implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-ktx:2.6.1'
implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-runtime-ktx:2.6.1'

//Coroutine testing
testImplementation 'org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-test:1.7.3'

// Import the Firebase BoM
implementation platform('com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:32.2.2')

// For instrumented tests.
androidTestImplementation 'com.google.dagger:hilt-android-testing:2.47'
// with Kotlin
        kaptAndroidTest 'com.google.dagger:hilt-android-compiler:2.47'
// ...with Java.
androidTestAnnotationProcessor 'com.google.dagger:hilt-android-compiler:2.47'

// When using the BoM, don't specify versions in Firebase dependencies
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics-ktx:21.3.0'


// Add the dependencies for any other desired Firebase products
// https://firebase.google.com/docs/android/setup#available-libraries

// Google Maps for Android
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:18.1.0'

// DataStore (SharedPreference replacement)
implementation "androidx.datastore:datastore-preferences:1.1.0-alpha04"

// Stripe Android SDK
implementation 'com.stripe:stripe-android:20.28.0'

//Picasso
implementation 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.71828'

// ARCore and Sceneform

// Provides ARCore Session and related resources.
implementation 'com.google.ar:core:1.38.0'

// Provides ArFragment, and other UX resources.
implementation 'com.google.ar.sceneform.ux:sceneform-ux:1.15.0'

// Alternatively, use ArSceneView without the UX dependency.
implementation 'com.google.ar.sceneform:core:1.15.0'


}

apply plugin: 'com.google.ar.sceneform.plugin'

sceneform.asset('sampledata/3DModels/FullHDPlasmaTV.fbx', // 'Source Asset Path' 
specified during import.
    'default',                            // 'Material Path' specified during import.
    'sampledata/3DModels/FullHDPlasmaTV.fbx',         // '.sfa Output Path' specified 
  during import.
    'src/main/res/raw/plasmatv')              // '.sfb Output Path' specified during 
import.

This is my build.gradle(project)

// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub- 
projects/modules.
buildscript {
ext.kotlin_version = '1.8.20'
ext.fragment_version = "1.6.0"
ext.coroutines_version = "1.6.0"
repositories {
    google()
    mavenCentral()
    mavenLocal()
}
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:8.0.2'
    classpath 'com.google.dagger:hilt-android-gradle-plugin:2.46.1'
    classpath 'com.google.dagger:hilt-android-testing:2.47@aar'
    classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
    classpath 'com.google.ar.sceneform:plugin:1.15.0'
    // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
    // in the individual module build.gradle files
  }
 }

 plugins {
 id 'com.android.application' version '8.0.2' apply false
 id 'com.android.library' version '8.0.2' apply false
 id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android' version '1.8.20' apply false
 }

 Finally, this is my Activity class:

 package com.tritongames.shoppingwishlist.presentation

 import android.content.Context
 import android.net.Uri
 import android.os.Bundle
 import android.view.GestureDetector
 import android.view.GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener
 import android.view.MotionEvent
 import android.widget.ImageView
 import android.widget.LinearLayout
 import android.widget.Toast
 import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
 import androidx.datastore.core.DataStore
 import androidx.fragment.app.FragmentContainerView
 import androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelProvider
 import com.google.android.material.snackbar.Snackbar
 import com.google.ar.core.Anchor
 import com.google.ar.core.Config
 import com.google.ar.core.Config.LightEstimationMode
 import com.google.ar.core.Frame
 import com.google.ar.core.HitResult
 import com.google.ar.core.Plane
 import com.google.ar.core.Session
 import com.google.ar.core.Trackable
 import com.google.ar.core.TrackingState
 import com.google.ar.core.exceptions.CameraNotAvailableException
 import com.google.ar.core.exceptions.UnavailableException
 import com.google.ar.sceneform.AnchorNode
 import com.google.ar.sceneform.ArSceneView
 import com.google.ar.sceneform.HitTestResult
 import com.google.ar.sceneform.Node
 import com.google.ar.sceneform.rendering.ModelRenderable
 import com.google.ar.sceneform.ux.ArFragment
 import com.squareup.picasso.Picasso
 import com.tritongames.shoppingwishlist.R
 import com.tritongames.shoppingwishlist.data.repository.bestbuy.BestBuyRepository
 import com.tritongames.shoppingwishlist.data.repository.category.ShopCategoryRepository
 import com.tritongames.shoppingwishlist.data.repository.userPreferences.UserPreferenceRepository
 import com.tritongames.shoppingwishlist.data.viewmodels.BestBuyViewModel
 import com.tritongames.shoppingwishst.data.viewmodels.ShoppingDataViewModel
 import com.tritongames.shoppingwishlist.util.ARSessionManager
 import com.tritongames.shoppingwshlist.util.BBViewModelFactory
 import com.tritongames.shoppingwishlist.util.DispatcherProvider
 import com.tritongames.shoppingwishlist.util.ShopDataViewModelFactory
 import dagger.hilt.android.AndroidEntryPoint
 import java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture
 import java.util.concurrent.CompletionStage
 import javax.inject.Inject



private fun <T> CompletableFuture<T>.exceptionally(run: Unit) {

}

private fun <T> CompletionStage<T>.thenAccept(renderable: T) {

}

@AndroidEntryPoint
class ShoppingARView : AppCompatActivity() {

private lateinit var imageGrid: LinearLayout
private lateinit var imgView: ImageView
private lateinit var bbVM: BestBuyViewModel
private lateinit var viewModelFactory: ViewModelProvider.Factory
private lateinit var shopDataVM: ShoppingDataViewModel
private lateinit var fragContainerView: FragmentContainerView
private lateinit var plasmaHDTV: ModelRenderable
private val pathPlasma: Int = R.raw.fullhdplasmatv
private var cameraPermission = false
private val arSessionManager: ARSessionManager = ARSessionManager()
private lateinit var frame: Frame
private val RC_PERMISSIONS = 0x123
val shopARFrag: ShoppingARFragment = ShoppingARFragment()
private lateinit var arFragment: ArFragment
private lateinit var arSceneView: ArSceneView
private var hasPlacedRenderable = false
private var gestureDetector: GestureDetector? = null
private var loadingMessageSnackbar: Snackbar? = null
private var hasFinishedLoading = false
private var cameraPermissionRequested = false


@Inject
lateinit var bbRepository : BestBuyRepository
@Inject
lateinit var userPreferenceRepository: UserPreferenceRepository
@Inject
lateinit var dispatchers: DispatcherProvider
@Inject
lateinit var shopCatRepository : ShopCategoryRepository
@Inject
lateinit var dataStore: DataStore<androidx.datastore.preferences.core.Preferences>


 override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

  //     val shoppingArviewBinding = 
  ActivityShoppingArviewBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
  setContentView(R.layout.activity_shopping_arview)

  if (!arSessionManager.checkIsSupportedDeviceOrFinish(this))
      return

  arFragment = supportFragmentManager.findFragmentById(R.id.ux_fragment) as ArFragment


  arFragment.setOnSessionInitializationListener {
      if (it != null) {
          // If the session wasn't created yet, don't resume rendering.
          // this@ShoppingARView can happen if ARCore needs to be updated or permissions 
   are not granted yet.
          try {
              val lightEstimationMode: Config.LightEstimationMode =
                  Config.LightEstimationMode.ENVIRONMENTAL_HDR
              val session: Session? =
                  if (cameraPermission)
                       arSessionManager.createArSessionWithInstallRequest(
                      this@ShoppingARView,
                      lightEstimationMode
                  ) else arSessionManager.createArSessionNoInstallRequest(
                      this@ShoppingARView,
                      lightEstimationMode
                  )
              if (session == null) {
                  cameraPermission =
                      arSessionManager.hasCameraPermission(this@ShoppingARView)

              } else {
                  arFragment.arSceneView.setupSession(session)
              }
          } catch (e: UnavailableException) {
              arSessionManager.handleSessionException(this@ShoppingARView, e)
          }


      }

  }

  arFragment.setOnTapArPlaneListener { hitResult, plane, motionEvent ->
      if (motionEvent.action == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
          if (hitResult != null) {
              val xPos = motionEvent.x
              val yPos = motionEvent.y
              Toast.makeText(
                  applicationContext,
                  "XPosition of touch $xPos and Yposition of touch $yPos",
                  Toast.LENGTH_LONG
              ).show()
          }
      } else if (motionEvent.action == MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE) {

      } else if (motionEvent.action == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {

      } else {

      }
  }


  // Set up a tap gesture detector.
  gestureDetector = GestureDetector(
      this,
      object : SimpleOnGestureListener() {
          override fun onSingleTapUp(e: MotionEvent): Boolean {
              onSingleTap(e)
              return true
          }

          override fun onDown(e: MotionEvent): Boolean {
              return true
          }
      })



  // Set a touch listener on the Scene to listen for taps.
  arSceneView = arFragment.arSceneView
  arSceneView
      .scene
      .setOnTouchListener { hit: HitTestResult?, event: MotionEvent? ->
          // If the solar system hasn't been placed yet, detect a tap and then check to 
    see if
          // the tap occurred on an ARCore plane to place the solar system.
          if (!hasPlacedRenderable) {
              return@setOnTouchListener event?.let { gestureDetector!!.onTouchEvent(it) 
      } == true
          }
          false
      }


  // Set an update listener on the Scene that will hide the loading message once a Plane 
  is
  // detected.
  arSceneView
      .scene
      .addOnUpdateListener {
          if (loadingMessageSnackbar == null) {
              return@addOnUpdateListener
          }
          val frame: Frame = arSceneView.arFrame ?: return@addOnUpdateListener
          if (frame.camera.trackingState != TrackingState.TRACKING) {
              return@addOnUpdateListener
          }
          for (plane in frame.getUpdatedTrackables(Plane::class.java)) {
              if (plane.trackingState === TrackingState.TRACKING) {
                  hideLoadingMessage()
              }
          }
      }
  arSessionManager.requestCameraPermission(this@ShoppingARView, RC_PERMISSIONS)

    viewModelFactory =  BBViewModelFactory(bbRepository, userPreferenceRepository, 
  dispatchers)
    bbVM = ViewModelProvider(this@ShoppingARView, viewModelFactory ) 
  [BestBuyViewModel::class.java]

  viewModelFactory =  ShopDataViewModelFactory(shopCatRepository, dispatchers, 
  dataStore)
  shopDataVM = ViewModelProvider(this@ShoppingARView, viewModelFactory ) 
  [ShoppingDataViewModel::class.java]

      imgView = ImageView(this@ShoppingARView)

    imageGrid = findViewById(R.id.image_grid)

    /*for(img in bbVM.getAllPS4Images()){
        Picasso.get().load(img.toUri()).into(imgView)
        imageGrid.addView(imgView)
    }*/

  for(img in shopDataVM.getProductImages()){
      Picasso.get().load("File:img").into(imgView)
      imageGrid.addView(imgView)
  }

 //      val camera: Camera = arSceneView.scene.camera
 //      camera.localRotation = Quaternion.axisAngle(Vector3.right(), -30.0f)




}

private fun onSingleTap(tap: MotionEvent) {
    if (!hasFinishedLoading) {
        // We can't do anything yet.
        return
    }
    val frame = arSceneView.arFrame
    if (frame != null) {
        if (!hasPlacedRenderable && tryPlaceShopItem(tap, frame)) {
            hasPlacedRenderable = true
        }
    }
}

private fun tryPlaceShopItem(tap: MotionEvent, frame: Frame): Boolean{
    if (frame.camera.trackingState == TrackingState.TRACKING) {
        for (hit: HitResult in frame.hitTest(tap)) {
            val trackable: Trackable = hit.trackable;
            if (trackable is Plane && trackable.isPoseInPolygon(hit.hitPose)) {
                // Create the Anchor.
                val anchor: Anchor = hit.createAnchor();
                val anchorNode: AnchorNode = AnchorNode(anchor);
                anchorNode.setParent(arSceneView.scene);
                val plasmaTV = get3DModel("fullhdplasmatv.glb", this)
                val nodeTV = Node()
                plasmaTV.thenAccept(plasmaTV.get())
                plasmaTV.exceptionally( plasmaTV.run {
                Toast.makeText(this@ShoppingARView, "Unable to load renderable", 
 Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                })

                anchorNode.addChild(nodeTV)
                hasFinishedLoading = true
                return true;
            }
        }
    }

    return false;
}


override fun onResume() {
    super.onResume()
    if (arSceneView.session == null) {
        // If the session wasn't created yet, don't resume rendering.
        // This can happen if ARCore needs to be updated or permissions are not granted 
 yet.
        try {
            val lightEstimationMode = LightEstimationMode.ENVIRONMENTAL_HDR
            val session: Session? =
                if (cameraPermissionRequested) 
 arSessionManager.createArSessionWithInstallRequest(
                    this,
                    lightEstimationMode
                ) else arSessionManager.createArSessionNoInstallRequest(this, 
 lightEstimationMode)
            if (session == null) {
                cameraPermissionRequested = arSessionManager.hasCameraPermission(this)
                return
            } else {
                arSceneView.setupSession(session)
            }
        } catch (e: UnavailableException) {
            arSessionManager.handleSessionException(this, e)
        }
    }

    try {
        arSceneView.resume()
    } catch (ex: CameraNotAvailableException) {
        arSessionManager.displayError(this, "Unable to get camera", ex)
        finish()
        return
    }

    if (arSceneView.session != null) {
        showLoadingMessage()
    }
}

override fun onPause() {
    super.onPause()
    arSceneView.pause()
}

override fun onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy()
    arSceneView.destroy()
}

private fun get3DModel(file: String, context: Context): 
 CompletableFuture<ModelRenderable> {

    return ModelRenderable.builder() //ModelRenderer.Builder
        .setSource(context, Uri.parse(file)) //Renderable
        .build() //CompletableFuture<Renderable>
}

fun showLoadingMessage() {
    if (loadingMessageSnackbar != null && loadingMessageSnackbar!!.isShownOrQueued()) {
        return
    }
    loadingMessageSnackbar = Snackbar.make(
        this@ShoppingARView.findViewById(android.R.id.content),
        com.tritongames.shoppingwishlist.R.string.plane_finding,
        Snackbar.LENGTH_INDEFINITE
    )
    loadingMessageSnackbar?.view?.setBackgroundColor(-0x40cdcdce)
    loadingMessageSnackbar?.show()
}

private fun hideLoadingMessage() {
    if (loadingMessageSnackbar == null) {
        return
    }
    loadingMessageSnackbar!!.dismiss()
    loadingMessageSnackbar = null
}

override fun onRequestPermissionsResult(
    requestCode: Int, permissions: Array<String?>, results: IntArray
) {
    super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, results)
    if (!arSessionManager.hasCameraPermission(this@ShoppingARView)) {
        if (!arSessionManager.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(this@ShoppingARView)) 
 {
            // Permission denied with checking "Do not ask again".
            arSessionManager.launchPermissionSettings(this@ShoppingARView)
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(
                this@ShoppingARView, "Camera permission is needed to run 
 this@ShoppingARView application", Toast.LENGTH_LONG
            )
                .show()
        }
        finish()
    }
}

/*override fun onWindowFocusChanged(hasFocus: Boolean) {
    super.onWindowFocusChanged(hasFocus)
    if (hasFocus) {
        // Standard Android full-screen functionality.
        window
            .decorView.systemUiVisibility = (View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE
                or View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_HIDE_NAVIGATION
                or View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN
                or View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION
                or View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN
                or View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE_STICKY)
        window.addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON)
    }
}*/


}
```

Comment: I'm struggling with the exact same thing at this moment, god is it frustrating :-D

Comment: I have an idea of where the error might be.  This line of code after putting a break point shows null:   val lightEstimationMode: Config.LightEstimationMode =
                  Config.LightEstimationMode.ENVIRONMENTAL_HDR.  Specifically, the ENVIRONMENTAL_HDR is null.  How to fix it, I'm still trying to figure out, perhaps I need a library or something?

Comment: The other problem that I'm facing is figuring out why even though I already have Google Play Service for AR, when I port the .apk to the phone and launch it, the phone asks me to update ArCore and then gets hung up there?

Comment: I think I've solved the problem by changing Config.LightEstimationMode.ENVIRONMENTAL_HDR to Config.LightEstimationMode.AMBIENT_INTENSITY.  It doesn't crash anymore